# Front End and Back End

Tags: web-applications, project

I am doing a Web Application using ASP.NET, C#, and SQL Server.

Which one of the following is correct usage:

**1. Front End :** ASP.NET

**Back End :** C#

**2. Front End :**ASP.NET

**Back End :**SQL Server

**3. Front End :** ASP.NET with C#

**Back End :** SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

**Backend**: C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server

**Frontend**: HTML/razor templates, CSS (or some CSS compiled language, like LESS or SASS), and whatever javascript libraries or frameworks you pick (eg. jQuery/Bootstrap/Angular...)

Answer (score 0):

**BackEnd** in web development (.Net)  but now we should ask if you want use web forms or mvc (Model-View-Controller).

-if you want use web forms Just know 
C#.
,.Net framework.
,Entity framework to access data from database (SqlServer-Oracle-Mysql) (insert,update,delete).

- if you want use mvc you need know a design pattern (Model-View-Controller) its better in web development.

Advanced but important

-Web Api

-Web Serveces

**FrontEnd**

you should know 
-HTML5
-CSS
-JavaScript
-Jquery

Advanced but now important in work

-Angular JS

-Node JS

-Signal R

-BootStrap

-Search engine optmization

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET** -middle and back-end part
**C#**  - Its a desktop programming language ,we use to make software using it.It has a web framework named ASP.NET 
**SQL Server** - It is a database server to store data from websites .But SQL(structured query language) is a language for entering data to SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

.net is used for front and back end both
Like asp.net is used for backend and vb.net is used for front end .
C# is also used for both back and frontend